# Как правильно родительном падеже: предтеч или предтечей?

Tags: родительный-падеж

Нечто, принадлежащее предтече или предтечам, это "нечто предтеч" или "нечто предтечей"?

Хорошо помню русский перевод игры Star Control II. В нём было "предтеч", но уверенности в правильности нет.

Comment: Можно ведь и [в словарь посмотреть](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/предтеча#Морфологические_и_синтаксические_свойства).

Comment: @dmitry ни в коем случае не навязываю своё мнение, но из ответа Сергея ясно, откуда у человека возник такой вопрос. Возможно, автор мог бы добавить - что интуитивно, по аналогии с похожими словами - он предпочитает тот вариант, которого почему-то нет в словарях.

Answer (score 3):

Вы не зря сомневаетесь: слова первого склонения с основой на мягкий согласный часто колеблются в выборе окончания: свеч - свечей, доль - долей.

Нормативным, как правило, является только один из вариантов, поэтому ответ нужно искать в нормативных словарях. Например, в "Грамматическом словаре" А. А. Зализняка дается только вариант "предтеч".

Викисловарь, не связанный обетом нормативности, дает оба варианта.

Замечу, что "нормативный" не  означает "единственно возможный" или даже что "так бы написал классик". Или вы что-то другое имели в виду под словом "правильно"?